# SlickGrid is displayed but data is not populated in the grid

Tags: json, slickgrid

SlickGrid is displayed but data is not populated in the grid. It is good with direct ajax call but the problem with dataview please can any one help me

```
  var jqxhr = $.getJSON('http://localhost:50305/Service1.svc/json/Projects', function (data) {
                          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                      slickdata[i] = {
                                          ProjectID: data[i].ProjectID,
                                          ProjectTypeID: data[i].ProjectTypeID,
                                          ProjectName: data[i].ProjectName,
                                      };
                                  }
                                  console.log("slickdata is" + slickdata);
                              dataView.onRowCountChanged.subscribe(function (e, args) {
                                      grid.updateRowCount();
                                      grid.render();
                                  });

                                  dataView.onRowsChanged.subscribe(function (e, args) {
                                      grid.invalidateRows(dataView.rows);
                                     grid.render();
                                  });

                                  dataView.beginUpdate();
                                  dataView.setItems(slickdata, "ProjectID");
                                  dataView.endUpdate();

                          dataView = new Slick.Data.DataView({ inlineFilters: true });
                        grid = new Slick.Grid("#teamGrid", dataView, columns, options);
```

Comment: Where's the output - can you please add it to the question?

Comment: Iam not able to insert output image it shows only column names and div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `Dataview` as you mentioned in a comment. You need couple of lines of code, and also need to add `data` to the `dataview` object. See the following:

```
// create DataView & Grid object
var dataView = new Slick.Data.DataView();
var grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", dataView, columns, options);

// then bind data to the DataView object
dataView.beginUpdate();
dataView.setItems(data);
dataView.endUpdate();
```

You can see a more complete example of DataView here: [Example4-model](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/gh-pages/examples/example4-model.html)

**EDIT**
Your question does not seem to have a unique `id` property inside your data, though SlickGrid specifically requires it and would throw an error in the console if you don't have that `id`. I usually prefer to fix this problem on the server side (PHP or whichever language you use). You could also add the `id` property via javascript something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  data.id = data[i].ProjectID; // clone your ProjectID into a new 'id' property
}

// then bind data to the DataView object
dataView.beginUpdate();
dataView.setItems(data);
dataView.endUpdate();
```

Comment: iam updating my question as you suggested but data was not binding

Comment: in your question I see 2 possible problems... 1- SlickGrid rely on the data array having a property of `id` (also all lower case) and has to be a unique id and inside your example you seem to have instead 'ProjectID' which is not named `id`, I suggest you change it at the source (server side)... 2- Why are you doing a `for` loop? No need, just pass the data directly as this `dataView.setItems(data);`

Comment: instead of changing ProjectId as id i wrote like this  dataView.setItems(slickdata, "ProjectID"); i am trying in both the ways directly pass 'data' and convert data into array and data is added to the dataview. last time struggled with same problem in that the format of json data is different but now i cant understand the problem here any way i will change and try my server code to change id

Comment: thnks for giving reply i got it   grid = new Slick.Grid("#teamGrid", dataView.rows, columns, options); here i am binding dataView.rows instead of dataView

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your comment... but as a suggestion, you should install Firebug (Firefox extension) to troubleshoot. That should help you, if you don't already have it.

Answer (score 0):

once the grid has been defined, you need to do

```
grid.init();
```

and since

```
alert(data);
```

is a json object the alert is correct. send the data to the console and you can see the json object there

Comment: Have a look at the dataview [link](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/DataView) The data needs to be added to the dataview (where you are using 'mydata') and then the grid.init() should be called

Comment: Iam using DataView like this  var dataview = new Slick.Data.DataView(); grid = new Slick.Grid("#teamGrid", dataview, columns, options);   but data is not added to the dataview.